# Quando é valido usar XACT_ABORT() em um script que já está utilizando TRY/CATCH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transações

Supondo o seguinte código:

```
/*
DROP TABLE #Teste;
CREATE TABLE #Teste(id INT);
INSERT INTO #Teste VALUES(1);
CREATE TABLE LogErros(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, nomeTransaction VARCHAR(100), errorMessage VARCHAR(500), horaErro DATETIME)
DROP TABLE LogErros
SELECT * FROM LogErros
*/


SET XACT_ABORT ON
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20) = 'TR_Teste';

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO #Teste VALUES(2);
    INSERT INTO #Teste VALUES(3);
    --INSERT INTO #Teste VALUES('Oi');

    COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TranName
    INSERT INTO LogErros VALUES(@TranName, CAST(ERROR_LINE() as VARCHAR) + ' - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE());
END CATCH
```

É valido o uso do `XACT_ABORT()` em casos assim?

Vi no stackoverflow internacional que a função anterior consegue tratar casos em que a procedure sofrer `timeout` por exemplo, problema que o `TRY/CATCH` não consegue tratar (*posso ter entendido errado*). Pensando nesse caso, então é valido o uso, correto?

Mas também vi pessoas falando que o `XACT_ABORT()` ficou obsoleto após o `TRY/CATCH`, isso é verdade? Sendo assim, o `TRY/CATCH` consegue tratar todos os erros sozinho?

Comment: Tô sem tempo para detalhar mais sobre isso, mas recomendo essa [leitura](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) ;)

Comment: Ótima leitura, @Tuxpilgrim, se deseja ganhar 10 pontos, caso ninguém responda a pergunta, pode transformar em pergunta que eu aceito.

Comment: Se até mais tarde alguém não responder faço isso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `TRY CATCH`

O `TRY CATCH` verifica se o código dentro do bloco`TRY` foi bem sucedido, caso contrário a execução é transferida para o bloco `CATCH` e o código de de manipulação de erro é executado. Mas, ele possui uma limitação que deve ser levada em conta:

> O `try catch` não captura erros de compilação que acontecem dentro do mesmo escopo!

O que pode ser um problema quando o seu código dentro do bloco `TRY` além de *query* simples executa *store procedures* ou *triggers*.

### `SET XACT_ABORT ON`

Usar o `SET XACT_ABORT ON` no início da *procedure* ativa uma opção que está desativada por padrão, mas é mais uma opção de segurança, em casos que o `TRY CATCH` não consegue lidar, como o citado acima.

Com o `XACT_ABORT ON` qualquer transação em aberta é revertida e imediatamente a execução é abortada, o que torna essa opção um tratamento de erro mais confiável para a manipulação de transações, em particular para o comportamento padrão das transações, onde existe várias situações em que a execução pode ser abortada sem qualquer transação sendo revertida, mesmo com o `TRY CATCH`.

Para uma boa manipulação dos erros, é importante o uso do `TRY CATCH` e do `SET XACT_ABORT`, sendo que os dois acabam por funcionar como complemento.

Deixo como leitura de referência os seguintes artigos:

- [Uma análise dos erros que o TRY CATCH não consegue tratar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/try-catch-doesnt-handle/) e
- [Uma boa explicação sobre a manipulação de erros (SQL SERVER)](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)